# DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-421, SQLSTATE=42826, SQLERRMC=null

Tags: sql, db2

I've never used DB2 before. there is a strange error.when I use jdbc to execute the following sql :

```
select id,name,description,sysflag from t_perm_template where sysflag=1
union all
select id,name,description,sysflag from t_perm_template where sysflag =2
```

> return error :DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-421, SQLSTATE=42826,
>   SQLERRMC=null....

but the sql could execute corretly in IBM Data Studio.

I searched on the ibm,42826-The rows of UNION, INTERSECT, EXCEPT, or VALUES do not have the same number of columns.but apparently,columns are the same.

why?

Comment: Is that the exact code you're trying to run or have you simplified it.  The code shown shouldn't be seeing that error.  In fact, the code shown doesn't need the UNION operation.  select id,name,description,sysflag from t_perm_template where sysflag in (1,2) is all you'd need.

Comment: I agree with @Charles - that query won't generate that error (nor is it necessary to use a `UNION ALL` in the first place).  My guess is that you've accidently dropped a comma in the `SELECT` list, which is causing one of the columns to be aliased, which would then manifest as 1 fewer columns...

Comment: Thanks for your (@Charles,@Clockwork-Muse) reply,It's almost the exact code,I used 'or' instead of 'union all', it worked.

Comment: check the results when you execute this query